# How to navigate to another page after clicking the image

Tags: javascript, php, html, xml

I have developed a memory game which works perfect. In the game page, when a match is found, the image is displayed on the right side of the page.
What i wanted is to navigate to another page when that image is clicked.

The another page is a tag management page, so I need to access the images and xml files.

the code i used to display the image when a match is found in game:

```js
function getpicture(){
  document.getElementById('picture').innerHTML = getgImage(event.target.dataset.number);

  pic = document.getElementById('picture').innerHTML;
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'maingame.php',
    data: {
      'pic': pic,
    },
  })
}
```

In the html side:

```php
<div class="imageside" id="picture"> <?php

  if (isset($_POST['pic'])) {
    $picture = $_POST['pic'];
    $link_array = explode('/', $picture);
    $imgpath = end($link_array);
    $ext = substr($imgpath, strrpos($imgpath, "."));
    $imgname = str_replace($ext, '', $imgpath);

    $dire = "Annotated Dataset/data/";

    $file = $dire.$imgname.'.xml';

    $xml = @simplexml_load_file(@$file);

    if(!empty($xml->globalvalidation->true)){
      $validclass = 'blurclass';
    }else{
      $validclass = 'img_src';
    }?>

  <img src="<?php echo "$picture"; ?>" class="<?php echo $validclass; ?>">

<?php } ?></div>

<script>
  $('.img_src').click(function(){
    var images = $(this).attr('src');
    var url = 'validation.php';
    var form = $('<form action="' + url + '" method="post">' +
      '<input type="text" name="img_url" value="' + images + '" />' +
      '</form>');
    $('body').append(form);
    form.submit();
  });
</script>
```

I tried the above code, but when i clicked the image, it does not navigate to the other page. I think I got lost somewhere in the between. Can someone help me where i went wrong, and help me to solve this problem to navigate to the next page on click on the image.

Comment: Don't you have any error in the console?

Comment: no errors in console

Comment: What if you add a submit button to the form and you click it manually? Will it submit and navigate? Can you give me a living example? It would be easier to debug.